# How do I move an image randomly across the screen?

Tags: android

I would like to move my mole image randomly across the screen, but I am not sure how to do this, could someone please assist me? I found some information about how to do it moving it from left to right but this is not what I am looking for thank you in advance.

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="@drawable/ground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moleImage"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/mole" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this works for you

```
ImageView iv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_random_image);

        iv = findViewById(R.id.moleimage);

        positionImage();
    }

    public void positionImage() {

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

        float randX = getRandomPositionX(DeviceTotalWidth);
        float randY = getRandomPositionY(DeviceTotalHeight);

        Log.d(TAG, "positionImage: totalX: " + DeviceTotalWidth + " totalY: " + DeviceTotalHeight);
        Log.d(TAG, "positionImage: ranX: " + randX + " ranY: " + randY);

        iv.setX(randX);
        iv.setY(randY);

    }

    public float getRandomPositionX(float deviceTotalWidth) {
        Random random = new Random();
        float randX = random.nextInt((int) deviceTotalWidth - (int) getImageSizeinPixels());
        return randX;
    }

    public float getRandomPositionY(float DeviceTotalHeight) {
        Random random = new Random();
        float randY = random.nextInt((int) DeviceTotalHeight - (int) getImageSizeinPixels());
        return randY;
    }

    public float getImageSizeinPixels() {
        // Converts 65 dip into its equivalent px
        float imageSize = 65f;
        float extraPadding = 40f;
        float dip = imageSize + extraPadding;
        Resources r = getResources();
        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                dip,
                r.getDisplayMetrics()
        );

        return px;
    }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need main `Layout` where you have `imageview` as child layout.
Add `onTouchListerner` to your main layout .Main layout can be any layout like `relativelayout`,`linearlayout` etc.

```
  mainlayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Now implement the `onTouch` method

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    float x = (float) event.getX();
    float y = (float) event.getY();
    yourImageView.setX(x);
    yourImageView.setY(y);
    return true;
}
```

I hope this will work for you.

Comment: This works it allows me to drag my image around but it's not what I'm looking for I would like my mole images to appear randomly on my screen.